# Как можно удалить данные объекта vue из памяти браузера, при переходе на другой компонент?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-chrome

Есть массив, который заполняется очень большим количеством данных, при переходе на другие части приложения через vue-router можно ли очистить данные этого массива, чтобы браузер потреблял меньше оперативной памяти?
Пробовала $destroy, но это не дает никакого эффекта, как и просто обнулить массив.

Comment: Если я правильно понял вопрос, то ответ: никак. Подобными вещами занимается сборщик мусора. Если Вам приниципиально, чтобы тот или иной набор данных затёрся в памяти, можно использовать WeakMap. [Вот здесь](https://learn.javascript.ru/weakmap-weakset) можно об этом почитать.

Comment: Спасибо, я попробую)